# Is there anyway to delete a SF object record using the PHP toolkit?

Tags: soql, custom-object, php, record, delete

I've this object relation:

```
    Group_Test__c   <--->   AssociationGroupOrder   <-->  Order
```

So I can have a N:N realtion between Groups and Orders.

I'm working with the ***PHP Toolkit***.

Insert records into *AssociationGroupOrder* is easy, just with:

```
        $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
        $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/wsdlSF.xml');
        $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        $records = array();

        //Insert a relationhsip record between Group & Order
        $records[0] = new stdclass();
        $records[0]->Order__c = $orderId;
        $records[0]->Group__c = $groupId;

        $response = $mySforceConnection->create($records, 'AssociationGroupOrder__c');
```

But, **how can I delete a record?** As far as I've seen, the *SforceEnterpriseClient()* class doesn't have a method for it...and it seems that the SOQL neither have a DELETE action in order to accomplish what I need, or am I wrong?

I thougth it would be easy (having the order ID and the group ID) to delete a record. But I can't find the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have delete method as part of the Standard Salesforce API and also included in the PHP toolkit.

you need to pass in the list / array of record ids to be deleted..

```
$deleteResult = $mySforceConnection->delete($ids);
```

here's a reference with sample code

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_(Enterprise)

Comment: Thanks! I only searched in the SforceEnterpriseClient.php file for the delete function. I didn't see the SforceBaseClient.php was included on it, and is in that file where the delete function is implemented.